# Given these 3 wireframe screenshots, what type of files in a MonoTouch solution would I need to make?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get started with some MonoTouch development. Using iMockups on my iPad, I quickly created 3 Views/Screens/Wireframe Screenshots of sample app I'm trying to do to learn.

Given these screenies, I'm not sure what files I should be creating with what controllers and/or views.

**I'm not after specific code .. just an *overall solution layout* and most importantly, seeing what type of controllers and view I should be doing.**

#### First Screen

A standard welcome page - has company logo, etc. Only thing you can do is sign into facebook ... which the button then goes to another view.

[image]

#### Second Screen

This screen is a `UIWebView` which embeds Facebook's application login webpage. Nothing fancy. Take note of the BACK button though.

[image]

#### Third Screen - User's home page

Once a user has authenticated via Facebook, they go here which gives them links to other views (ie. the 4 icon-buttons on the bottom `UIToolBar`).

[image]

So I thought i'd need a few more files ...

- `HomePageUINavigationController` :: this is the root controller for the homepage and login page.
- `HomePageViewController` :: this would be a `UIViewController` which has the contents of the First Screen. The sign in button links to the `FacebookViewController` (next)..
- `FacebookViewController` :: Screen 2 - this would be a `UIViewController` with a `UIWebView` on it. This links back to `HomePageViewController` somehow.
- `UserUITabBarController` :: Screen 3 - connects to some other subviews via the `TabBar` icons that link off... The only way to get to Screen 1 is if we logout ... which could be one of the 4 TabBar icons (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Small point - on the facebook authentication if you use the latest Facebook iOS code it will utilize the facebook app (if installed) and if you are running one of the later versions of iOS.  It takes a lot of the work away and moreover removes the need for the use of embedded web pages unless it absolutely has to.